# How to open a link without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been observing that whenever I click a link in phpMyAdmin it opens the respective link without refreshing the page. I have searched on the internet but I don't get a proper solution. If anyone knows the way to do it, please tell me. I don't want answers like: `document.write()` or `document.open`. They don't work as I expect. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What you're referring to is called a **Single Page Application**. JavaScript Frameworks and Libraries like *Angular* and *React* are responsible for such applications.

Search on how you can achieve the same in PHP

Comment: Ok Thanks! I will search on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question

To achieve what I have asked in the question, you need to use **Single Page Application** frameworks. Using single page application, *we can navigate between pages of the same site without letting the page reload all its contents*. You can use any of the Single Page Application frameworks like **React, Next.JS (recommended), Angular, Vue.JS etc**.

Comment: Since this was suggested to you in a comment several years ago, it's best to reply to the comment and ask the user if they would like to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to refresh without reloading the whole page? If you want to make such a single-page web application, there is a technique called **Ajax**. You can refer to it by going through this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp). Thank You!

Comment: What I want is to change the whole page's content. I don't want to change the contents partially.